# ARM FRDM-KE02Z How to read input from pins

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, keil, nxp-microcontroller

I`m new to ARM programming, but I have to do project to study. I Have [FRDM-KE02Z40M](https://www.nxp.com/design/development-boards/freedom-development-boards/mcu-boards/freedom-development-platform-for-kinetis-ke02-mcus:FRDM-KE02Z40M) development board (with KE02Z64VQH2 microcontroller). Firstly I wrote library for seven-segment display and it works fine. Next I tried to write library for buttons, but I have some problems with seting pins for input properly and reading from PDIR. I built system as shown:

[image]

And I wrote test code to checkout how it works.

```
void button_init(){
   GPIO_PinInit(GPIO_PTE5, GPIO_PinOutput);
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, GPIO_PTB0_MASK, GPIO_PinInput);
}

uint32_t button_read(){
   return (GPIOA -> PDIR) & (1UL << 8);
}

void led_test(){
   GPIO_PinClear(GPIO_PTE5);
   for(uint32_t i; i <= 3000000; i++){};
   GPIO_PinSet(GPIO_PTE5);
   for(uint32_t i; i <= 3000000; i++){};
   GPIO_PinClear(GPIO_PTE5);
   for(uint32_t i; i <= 3000000; i++){};
   GPIO_PinSet(GPIO_PTE5);
   for(uint32_t i; i <= 3000000; i++){};
   GPIO_PinClear(GPIO_PTE5);
   for(uint32_t i; i <= 3000000; i++){};

   }

int main(){
   sysinit();
   button_init();

   GPIO_PinClear(GPIO_PTE5);

   while(1){
   if (button_read()){led_test();}
   }
}
```

I`m using libraries delivered from NXP site: gpio.h and sysinit.c

Program should activate method for blinking every time I push button, but LED is blinking all the time when I hold button and when I release it.

Before that I wrote:

```
while(1){
   if(button_read()){
      GPIO_PinSet(GPIO_PTE5);
   }else{
      GPIO_PinClear(GPIO_PTE5);
   }
}
```

LED gave weak light and when I pushed button LED turned off. Then I swaped Set with Clear and LED 
behaved still the same.

Am I missing something in software? Or should I check connection and my hardware?
How should I set up pins for input and how I should read them properly?

Comment: Since your button is active high, have you tried adding a pull down resistor to the gpio side of the button? (Something like 10k would be fine to try it)

Comment: I connected pull down resistor on the same side of button that 5V is connected and on the oposite side I connected input board pin. Now it works correctly :) Thank you very much for your answer you saved my life and my 
career ;) I read about pull down resistors and I figured out that without this input pin was floating and I could read noise from board and It could be cause of strange behavior of board.

Comment: Not being a software issue, this should be on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  If embedded systems is to be your career, you need to at least get some basic knowledge of electronics.  Invest in a copy of [AoE](https://www.cambridge.org/vi/academic/subjects/physics/electronics-physicists/art-electronics-3rd-edition?format=HB)

Comment: Note that all GPIO pins on your part have a programmable _pull-up_ resistor on-chip when set as _input_.  You can simplify your design by using that rather then an external resistor.  You would have to change the circuit to be _normally-high_ (i..e _input-switch-GND_), but that _is_ then a matter of software (_active-low switch_: `return (GPIOA -> PDIR) & (1UL << 8) == 0;`).

Comment: @clifford in this case, it was more of a hardware problem and that stack exchange site is much better for this kind of thing, but I think this does straddle the line as it might have been a code issue. Speaking of, you're right to point of parts like this frequently have internal, software configurable pullups (and sometimes pulldowns) that are much nicer to use; but I don't have the reference material for this part to help op out with that, but they should spend some time and look up the info on that gpio configuration.

Comment: @aFku glad it worked out; typically you can't be 100% sure how it will behave unless you make sure you well define it; which is always a good thing to do :)